# Weird value from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I got a NSDictionary that when I do a [currentOrder debugDescription] call on it the layout is below, when I then do a:

```
[currentOrder valueForKey: @"itemOrder"]
```

It return it funny with the brackets as:

```
(
    "4 X ESPRESSO"
)
```

where it should only be (without brackets):

```
4 X EXPRESSO
```

Any idea why?

Content of currentOrder:

```
currentOrder: <__NSArrayM 0x68426c0>(
{
    extra1Select = 0;
    extra2Select = 0;
    extra3Select = 0;
    itemCost = 58;
    itemOrder = "4 X ESPRESSO";
    itemOrderDescription = "Cookie: YES, Sugar: YES";
    itemQuantity = 4;
    itemRestaurant = VidaECaffe;
    plistItem =     {
        cost = "11.5";
        description = "R11.50";
        extra1 =         {
            desc = Cookie;
            details =             (
                                {
                    cost = "3.00";
                    option1 = YES;
                },
                                {
                    cost = "0.00";
                    option2 = NO;
                }
            );
        };
        extra2 =         {
            desc = Sugar;
            details =             (
                                {
                    cost = "0.00";
                    option1 = YES;
                },
                                {
                    cost = "0.00";
                    option2 = NO;
                }
            );
        };
        itemRestaurant = VidaECaffe;
        level = 1;
        title = ESPRESSO;
    };
}
)
```

Comment: well - it seems right to me. 
What problem do you actually have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `currentOrder` is not a dictionary but a `NSArray` containing a dictionary. The failure you are making next is that you use `valueForKey:` which is part of the key value coding family and not the designated access method for dictionaries (which is `objectForKey:`), and the array returns you a filtered array as a result...

Answer (score 0):

When you print out the value of an array or dictionary in the debugger, the debugger includes the extra brackets, braces, and whatnot so you can see the layout of the structure you are asking about.

If the debugger shows the contents of an array something like

```
(
    "Foobar"
)
```

it's telling you that the array has one element, a string with the value `Foobar`.

Put entirely another way: Read up on what the debugger does when it prints out values. Lots of resources here and on the web for this. For example: [Debugging with GDB: Introduction to Commands, Print and Print-Object](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/debugging/debugging-with-gdb-introduction-to-commands.html)